# PHP 7.2 each is deprecated. Convert for each to foreach

Tags: php, deprecated

I got these 2 functions that throw DEPRECATED notices on php 7.2

```
function session_unregister($var) {
    global $session;

    for (reset($session->vars); list($i)=each($session->vars);) {
        if ($session->vars[$i] == trim($var)) {
            unset($session->vars[$i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

function session_is_registered($var) {
    global $session;

    for (reset($session->vars); list($i)=each($session->vars);) {
        if ($session->vars[$i] == trim($var)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I tried to modify them to be compatible with the new php, using foreach like so:

Changing:

```
for (reset($session->vars); list($i)=each($session->vars);) {
```

To:

```
foreach (array_keys($session->vars) as $i) {
```

But I am not 100% sure if that is the correct identical adaptation. Any comments?

Comment: who wrote that `for (reset($session->vars); list($i)=each($session->vars);)` ? incredible...

Comment: lol... yeah, I wonder the same. there are even more incredible examples... :)

Comment: wow, that's completly unreadable. Lucky for you that now throws Notices... You can just use a simple foreach

Comment: His name is CreativeMind ;) That does him honor.

Comment: haha...I didn't write that application, Ron, I am just working on its adaptation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need array keys:

```
foreach ($session->vars as $key=>$sesion_var) {
if ($sesion_var == trim($var)) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

or to be more consistent to rest of your code:

```
foreach ($session->vars as $i=>$sesion_var) {
 if ($session->vars[$i] == trim($var)) {
    return true;
 }
}
```

or maybe you should be using array_search() instead of that code block:

```
if(array_search(trim($var), $session->vars)) return true;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the second code block correct? I see `$session_var` on the first line, but not on the second line where it is says `$session->vars`, unlike the first code block above it.

Comment: @CreativeMind, it is correct, but it is not efficient like first or third solution. I have just placed it as example if you want to swap only one line of code. But I would suggest to refactor and optimize your code. It won't take you too much time, but it helps in increasing performance of code execution

Comment: This app has thousands of files of code to refactor and optimize, so surely lots of time :) Thanks for your answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
function session_unregister(string $var): void
{
    global $session;

    $var = trim($var);

    if (isset($session->vars[$var])) {
        unset($session->vars[$var]);
    }
}

function session_is_registered(string $var): bool
{
    global $session;

    return isset($session->vars[trim($var)]);
}
```

However if you rewrite the app, I would recommend to get rid of that `global` too and pass the session as argument to each function.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think they wanna pay for a complete app rewrite, just necessary minimal adaptations, but we'll discuss.